# Unable to display value which is returned from Spring controller

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

I'm trying to display like ${mesg}, it's not displaying the content, which is coming from the Spring controller. I have tried many ways, but no luck.

```
<html> 
    <head> <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"> 
         <title>HOME</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div align="center"> ${mesg} </div> 
     </body> 
</html>


@RequestMapping(value="/savefile",method=RequestMethod.POST) 
public String getStatus(@PathParam("pwd") String Pwd,ModelMap map){ 
    System.out.println(":::pwd::"+Pwd); 
    map.addAttribute("mesg", "Welcome to mBOK"); 

    return "Success"; 
}
```

Comment: Without any code how would you imagine anyone can help with this?

Comment: <html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>HOME</title>
 
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    ${mesg}  
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Spring controller : 

 @RequestMapping(value="/savefile",method=RequestMethod.POST)  
 public String getStatus(@PathParam("pwd") String Pwd,ModelMap map){
  System.out.println(":::pwd::"+Pwd);
  map.addAttribute("mesg", "Welcome to mBOK"); 
  
  return "Success";
 }

Comment: can you plz check and let me know